# Can a TextPointer be created with a specified LogicialDirection?

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-3.5

I'm having trouble getting desired behavior in a WPF RichTextBox.  I am creating a Span in code and applying a format and I want to position the cursor after the Span (so newly typed text won't be formatted).  From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textpointer.getinsertionposition.aspx), it sounds like:

```
editor.CaretPosition = span.ElementEnd.GetInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward)
```

should give me the behavior I seek:

> If the TextPointer already points to a
>   valid insertion position, but the
>   closing tag for a non-empty formatting
>   sequence directly follows that
>   position in the given direction, then
>   the TextPointer returned by this
>   method is adjusted to point to the
>   insertion position just after the
>   close of the formatting sequence.

But in practice I get a TextPointer with Backward direction unless the last character is a space and Backward direction results in new text being formatted.  I've tried some of the other, similar methods on TextPointer without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working by calling GetPositionAtOffset(0, LogicalDirection.Forward) on the TextPointer.